# what's the data source url for LDAP type

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, ldap

I am using Spring jdbc api to connect to a Oracle database. Only LDAP style of connection is provided to that particular database, and I succeeded in making the connection from Oracle's database client SQL developer.

One thing seems odd to me is the format of the connection string:

```
xyz.loc.biz.com:4050:4049
```

it worked when applied in SQL developer, however you would notice that there are two numbers which supposedly represent port number, but why two?

Nevertheless I used the above url in my code, which looks like:

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource(){
    SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://xyz.loc.biz.com:4050:4049/...");

    ds.setDriver(new OracleDriver());
    ds.setUsername("xxxxxx");
    ds.setPassword("yyyyyy");

    try(Connection conn = ds.getConnection()){
        log.info("conn={}",conn);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    };
    return ds;
}
```

Not surprisingly it shows an error like:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4050:4049"
```

Anyone can help?

Settings in SQL developer:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be having two ports in your connection string, why do you think that is correct?

Comment: I don't think it's correct, however the fact remains that I observed it worked when used as LDAP server in SQL developer. That strikes me as odd, and that is why I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Have you tried leaving one of those port numbers off?

Comment: Tried already-didn't work

Comment: One more thing: I remember I saw 'ldaps' somewhere, is it a secured version of LDAP protocol like HTTPS or something else?

Comment: @J.E.Y Yes `ldaps` means secure ldap or ldap over ssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if you specify two port numbers the first is used for the `ldap` protocol, the second for the `ldaps` protocol (found a hint at http://yong321.freeshell.org/oranotes/OracleConnectionSetup.html, the following is more definitive: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/ldap.htm).

It can be that the Oracle JDBC driver does not understand this syntax. Please try if one of these alternative connection strings work for you:

```
ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://xyz.loc.biz.com:4050/...");
ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldaps://xyz.loc.biz.com:4049/...");
```

Comment: ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://xyz.loc.biz.com:4050/..."); worked. Thanks for the help. To be complete, I've updated my post by adding one screenshot of the setting in SQL developer.